# Make changes to change_form.html in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

In my default change_form.html, there are three inputs in the form. One checkbox and two text inputs. 
I want to remove one of the text inputs so that I have one checkbox and one text input only.

how to do this?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Answer (score 1):

Say you have fields like:

User(Model Name) :

- first_name -> Text Input
- last_name  -> Text Input
- is_admin -> Checkbox

To remove last_name field, in your admin.py add a class like

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('last_name', ) //or fields = ('first_name', 'is_admin')

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Please go through the docs and tutorial for more details on this.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I think I put the question wrong. I wanted to ask, how to do it manually. The reason I want to do this way, I want an access to that particular input so that I can bind ajax code to it

Comment: In that case you would need to override the change form template and add the custom form template itself. Here is the document for the same: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Comment: Again, If you simply wanna add some autocomplete options to it, there are a lot of apps that provide similar functionality, you could use any one of them.